# Self extracting setup with Visual Studio 2015 Installer project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, setup-project

I could not figure out how to create self extracting setup with Visual Studio 2015 Installer project.

The installer project creates only .msi file and the setup.exe that launches the msi.

Answer (score 0):

Same question as this?

[Making .exe installable file for Windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32763553/making-exe-installable-file-for-windows-application/32768188#32768188)

Something like WinZip is the short answer.